# why transition component not work in vue2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to change my background color with transition when load component,
here is my code(I hide my JavaScript part,all my js part working well):

```
<template>
  <transition name="page-one-load">
    <div class="page-one" v-if="load">
      <div class="page-one-back">
        <el-cascader
          class="page-one-years"
          v-model="value"
          :options="options"
          :show-all-levels="false"
          :props="{ expandTrigger: 'hover' }"
          @change="handleChange"
          placeholder="请选择年份"
        ></el-cascader>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.page-one {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.page-one-load-enter {
  background: rgb(255, 0, 157);
}

.page-one-load-enter-active {
  transition: background 3s ease-in 0.1s;
}

.page-one-load-enter-to {
  background: rgb(38, 180, 45);
}
</style>
```

I guess there were some trouble in my code:

- transition component name is confilcit with my other components.
- transition class has lower priority.

I had tried my best to solve these problems, but still not working, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I want to have the transition effect when this component mounted firstly.Just now, I read the vue2 document transition part in detail and find first mount transition part.So I amend my code like this:

```
<template>
  <transition name="page-one-load" appear>
   ...
  </transition>
</template>
```

Yes, I append 'appear' modifier to transition label, then it worked!